# Why doesn't Task<T> implement IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

`Task<T>.ContinueWith` has the same basic underlying concept as `IObservable<T>.Subscribe`. They are similar enough for Reactive Extension to provide a conversion extension method. Since `IObservable<T>` is part of the BCL, there is no reason not to implement `IObservable<T>`. So, what is the reasoning behind `Task<T>` not implementing `IObservable<T>`?

Comment: ..a proper answer to this question requires a member of the TPL team to respond or someone with similar intimate knowledge of the team's decision making process.. unless I'm just missing something that's obvious to an outsider.

Comment: "Why" questions are generally not good questions.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - "Why" questions are great questions!  They might not be good questions *for StackOverflow*, though, admittedly. ;)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I suspect that " TPL team" is called ["PFX team"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/)? And its member Stephen Toub [has  already responded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806306/200449) to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it would be pertinent to quote Stephen Toub, MSFT (*) from his:

## [ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour - #2 - Task.ToObservable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990349.aspx) MSDN blog article:

> As it turns out, while `Task<TResult>` does not **currently** implement `IObservable<T>`, it’s actually quite a good fit to do so.  An observable represents any number of values terminated by either an end of the stream or by an exception.  A `Task<TResult>` **fits** this description: it completes with either a single value or with an exception.  While it’s possible that a future version of the .NET Framework will see `Task<TResult>` implement `IObservable<T>`, we can get the relevant behavior now by implementing it as an extension method for `Task<TResult>`; in fact, **Rx** includes just such an extension method, as does `ParallelExtensionsExtras`

(*)  not sure what "FT" means, except that MSFT is NASDAQ stock symbol meaning MS, but ["MS" in "MSFT" certainly means Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/stephen%20toub%20-%20msft/)

Comment: MSFT is just an abbreviation for Microsoft: *M*icro*S*o*FT*

Comment: @Brandon, wow, thanks a lot. At last. Was thinking about separate words (like "foundation" and team")

Answer (score 3):

This was covered very well by the Rx team with [their 2.0 beta blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx).  It is a *massive* post, although there's tons of great information in there.

preemptive tl;dr = IObservable is for sequences of future results, Task is for a single future result

The diagram that I think does the best job of explaining the relationship is in that post, but unfortunately pretty far down (and as I mentioned, it's a very large post :)

[image: Rx vs Task]

While the whole post is worth reading (IMHO), the relevant text about how Rx / Task / async/await all fit together starts at the heading "Rx v2.0 and .NET 4.5 “async” / “await” – a better together story"

Comment: The Parrallel Extensions team said it themselves that Task<T> is a good fit for IObservable<T> in a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990349.aspx). The Rx team is not responsible for who implements their interface.

Comment: Stephen's post on pfxteam predates the Rx 2.0 post by 2 years and obviously predates Rx 2.0. Task can be used with IObservable with Rx 2.0 as the Rx post describes, but as Stephen shows in that post from 2010, it's a single-result observable. IObservable is about a collection of future values. Always treating tasks as IObservable is possible, but you'd end up with the same kinds of code as if you forced synchronous code to pass everything as IEnumerable, even if it was just a single value being passed. :) The key bit is the conceptual difference, which that diagram explains very well IMHO.

Comment: I can see what would be wrong with that code in the case of `IEnumerable<T>`; however, I do not understand what is wrong with `Task<T>` implementing `IObservable<T>` as it should logically implement it because it contains the same methods and it would not lead to terrible code like treating every single value as an enumerable.

Comment: Why wouldn't it lead to terrible code?  Every place that was getting a Task<T> and doing a simple await (or whatever else with it) now needs to be changed to handle an ongoing steam of future results. If your response is that you'd document it as only returning a single future result, that's the same as returning an IEnumerable or T[] with only 1 item. The natural response is 'if you're only going to return 1 item, then just return that item!' (T for sync, Task<T> for async).

Comment: The 'contains same methods' I don't understand - IObservable only has 1 method, Subscribe, and there's no such method in IEnumerable or Task AFAICT? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess, but I think there are some good reasons:

1. `Task<T>` and `IObservable<T>` don't actually have the same underlying concept. Yes, both are asynchronous, but that's pretty much where all the commonality ends. The big difference between the two is that `Task<T>` always has a single value, `IObservable<T>` can have as many values (or as little, including zero) as it wants.

   If `Task<T>` implemented `IObservable<T>`, it would be similar as if every `T` in .Net implemented `IEnumerable<T>`, returning a single result, the object itself.
2. It is trivial to convert `Task<T>` to `IObservable<T>`. Either using [the `ToObservable()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244341%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) from Rx, or by [writing it yourself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990349.aspx). This makes what you're asking for much less necessary.

Comment: The Parrallel Extensions team said it themselves that Task<T> is a good fit for IObservable<T> in a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990349.aspx). The second part of point one is incorrect. Viewing this from a logical standpoint, A task is observable and reactive; meanwhile, a single object is not a collection unless it implements the interface.

Comment: @SaagarAhluwalia Yes, `Task` is observable, but it's observable **single value**. `IObservable` represents **multiple observable values**. I don't think that's incorrect, those are the definitions of the two types.

Comment: As you say yourself, observables "can have as many values (or as little, including zero) as it wants". Therefore, it's a perfect candidate for implementing IObservable, event though it only represents a single value. (Actually, it's zero to one values.)

Comment: @PatrikHägne According to this logic, you should be able to treat each object as a collection that contains that one object. E.g. `int` should implement `IEnumerable<int>`. I don't think that would be a good idea, and so I think `Task` shouldn't implement `IObservable` either.

Comment: No, it does not follow the same semantic at all, your logic is way off. A simple value should not be ```IEnumerable<T>```, just the same as a simple value should not implement ```IObservable<T>```. There's a big difference between a Task and a simple value, a Task represents an operation (that can fail). Therefore it's observable. It would be more similar to having ```Nullable<T>``` implement ```IEnumerable<T>```, which would make some sense.

Comment: @svick, what would be the drawbacks of having ```Task<T>``` implement ```IObservable<T>```? Even if your reasoning would hold up I can't see any drawbacks, only benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, while the `Task<T>` type is in the .NET framework, the Reactive Extensions (Rx) and `IObservable<T>` are not. The `System.Reactive` assembly has `System.Threading.Tasks` as a dependency, so nothing in the latter can reference the former.

If and when they add Rx to .NET, they may do as you're suggesting.

## Edit:

I may have spoken too quickly, actually. [Take a look in the documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) It appears that the `IObservable<T>` interface actually exists in the `mscorlib` assembly in .NET 4 and 4.5. So what I said above isn't a completely valid reason. I'm revising my guess reason to "Because they haven't integrated Rx into .NET yet" rather than "It's not possible currently because of circular dependencies."

Comment: I'd hope there's a "yet" in there - rx is just plain cool. :)

Comment: @JerKimball Since Rx is open source it will never happen.  It is better that way, anyways.

Comment: The only thing necessary to actually implement the interface is, well, the interface. That is like saying no one should implemented IEnumerable<T> in .Net 3.0 because linq was not in the framework. IObservable<T> is stand alone and does not *need* the Rx library to operate as one can still subscribe, which is its main function.